# How can I control the location of a dialog when using ShowDialog to display it?

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

This is a very trivial problem but I can't seem to find a way of solving it. It's annoying me because I feel I should know the answer to this, but I'm either searching for the wrong terms or looking at the wrong methods and properties.

I have a configuration dialog that's called from two places.

The first is from the button on the form which is working correctly - as you'd expect.

The second is from a context menu on the notifyIcon in the system tray, but here it appears at the top left of the screen. Ideally I'd like it to appear centered on the primary screen, or perhaps close to the system tray.

- I've tried setting the `Location`, but this appears to be overridden when `dialog.ShowDialog()` is called.
- I've tried using the `dialog.ShowDialog(IWin32Window)` overload, but that didn't seem to like me passing `null` as the window handle.
- I've tried using `dialog.Show()` instead, but (and this is where I could be going wrong) setting the location doesn't appear to give consistent results.
- I've even tried setting the `dialog.Parent` property - which of course raised an exception.

I just know that I'm going to realise that the answer is obvious when I (hopefully) see some answers, but at the moment I'm completely stuck.

*Thanks for the answers - as I suspected it was obvious, but as usual I'd got myself stuck into looking down the wrong route. The even more annoying thing is that I've used this property from the designer too.*

Comment: Had the same problem. For me it worked to set Location during Load event

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can set the [`Form.StartPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx) property to `FormStartPosition.Manual` and then set the [`Form.Location`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159414.aspx) property to your desired location.  When you call `ShowDialog` the form should show up in the desired location.

```
MyForm frm = new MyForm();
frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
frm.Location = new Point(10, 10);
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: System.Drawing.Point is the full name of the Point Class

Comment: Thanks for the example of how to overcome it. Apparently the StartPosition property can also be set through the designer. What an unexpected setting. Sharp edges still hanging people up after all these years.

Answer (score 22):

I assume you're using a Form, in which case you can use Form.StartPosition enumeration.  You can find more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx) and the enumeration behavior [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Try the StartPosition property on the form.