# MDI Child.show() displays the form in a weird manner

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

I have a main form that has 5 MDI children. When the main form is created, the mdi children are created and shown as well.

I assign them different locations on the screen, but when they're shown they start with the default location and move in a disturbing way to the new locations. I tried to assign the location before I show the forms , but as expected after calling the.Show() they tend to go to some default location.
Is there anyway to avoid showing this movement from the default to the new locations?

Here's  a code fragment

```
groupSettingsForm.Show();
        groupSettingsForm.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        dsForm.Show();
        dsForm.Location = new Point(groupSettingsForm.Width, 0);
        dPlots.Show();
        dPlots.Location = new Point(groupSettingsForm.Width, dsForm.Height);
        alertsForm.Show();
        alertsForm.Location = new Point(groupSettingsForm.Width, dsForm.Height + dPlots.Height);
        dataValuesForm.Show();
        dataValuesForm.Location = new Point(0, groupSettingsForm.Height);
```

I tried this, but it didn't work for me

```
   groupSettingsForm.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        groupSettingsForm.Show();

        dsForm.Location = new Point(groupSettingsForm.Width, 0);
        dsForm.Show();

        dPlots.Location = new Point(groupSettingsForm.Width, dsForm.Height);
        dPlots.Show();

        alertsForm.Location = new Point(groupSettingsForm.Width, dsForm.Height + dPlots.Height);
        alertsForm.Show();

        dataValuesForm.Location = new Point(0, groupSettingsForm.Height);
        dataValuesForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had something similar to this - [my question can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998675/how-can-i-control-the-location-of-a-dialog-when-using-showdialog-to-display-it).

You need to set the `StartPosition` property to `FormStartPosition.Manual`:

```
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
form.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
```