# Get cursor position in c#

Tags: c#

I have an application like this:

[image]

The yellow form will appear when user click to a button on the main Form and i want that yellow form appear at the position where the cursor is pointing to. (in the picture is button number 26). But it just appears somewhere else (just like picture too)

Here is my onClick event of button on the main form:

```
ChooseAnswer Answer = new ChooseAnswer();
Answer.Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
Answer.ShowDialog();
```

What's wrong with this?

Sorry about my english!

**OK the solution is:**

```
ChooseAnswer Answer = new ChooseAnswer();
Answer.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
Answer.Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
Answer.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Where is this code located, inside a click handler for these buttons? Or you want this form to move around with your mouse, like a tooltip?

Comment: no. just appear when i click the button with number in it (in the main form)

Comment: I think the cursor position you get is relative to the window, not to the screen.

Comment: any idea to fix that? :(

Comment: @Wimmel: `Cursor.Position` returns screen coordinates. But the problem is that `ShowDialog` uses `Form.StartPosition` to determine its initial position, and it has to be set to `Manual`, like [described in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998675/how-can-i-control-the-location-of-a-dialog-when-using-showdialog-to-display-it).

Comment: I have found the solution! But still thank you! :)

Comment: Tuan, please do share what you changed to fix so it will help others who are looking for the same answer. Thanks,

Comment: @tuankhoa1996: Note also that you don't need to create a new `Point` struct, simply set `Form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;` and `Form.Location = Cursor.Position;` and you're fine.

Comment: oh! good point. thank you so much @Groo! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
ChooseAnswer Answer = new ChooseAnswer();
Answer.Top = Cursor.Position.Y;
Answer.Left = Cursor.Position.X;
Answer.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Please leave comment for -1

Comment: still appear in some weird location! :(

Comment: @Irshad: `Top` and `Left` do nothing more than simply change `Form.Location` properties, end result will be equal to what OP has now.