# Problems with ShowDialog in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I use showdialog for show modal windows, but i have a problem in some computers with windows XP or windows 7 the parent window show in front after show a second modal window. My program is in .NET 4. Any suggestion?

In my main window i have a button with the code:

```
private void btnBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmBox fBox = new frmBox();
    fBox.ShowDialog();
}
```

And my code in a button inner frmBox is:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmSearch fSearch = new frmSearch();
    fSearch.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a short code sample that will reproduce the problem? Also, what do you mean by *"some computers with windows XP or windows 7"*? Do you really mean *"**ALL** computers with windows XP or windows 7"*? Or is it inconsistent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998675/how-can-i-control-the-location-of-a-dialog-when-using-showdialog-to-display-it

Comment: did you tried the property -  Topmost = true?

Comment: You should not use Windows XP for security reasons.

Comment: My program work fine in many computers with Windows XP and Windows 7, i have two computer with this problem

Comment: I moved your example code from the "answer" you posted in to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Show the dialog using the [`ShowDialog` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes another `Form` as an argument. This will set the dialog's `Owner` to that form.  [Owned forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) are always displayed on top of their owner.

From MSDN:

> When a form is owned by another form, it is closed or hidden with the
>   owner form. For example, consider a form named Form2 that is owned by
>   a form named Form1. If Form1 is closed or minimized, Form2 is also
>   closed or hidden. **Owned forms are also never displayed behind their
>   owner form.**

The following code is usually sufficient, but you may need to modify the argument depending on where you are opening the dialog from.

```
someForm.ShowDialog(this);
```